# Passport profile id

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

I'm using passport.js to provide OAuth authentication to my node.js app. But I do have one doubt:

When I receive the profile object when authenticating (when you define the OAuth strategy) is unique for all the providers or is specific for that provider?

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
    clientID: conf.fb.appId,
    clientSecret: conf.fb.appSecret,
    callbackURL: "http://local.host:3000/auth/facebook/callback"   },   function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    var user = users[profile.id] || 
                (users[profile.id] = { id: profile.id, name: profile.username });
    done(null, user);   } ));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is specific to the provider.  In this case, it will be the Facebook ID.

It is recommended that you create your own user record (in the database of your choice), and associate provider IDs with that record.  Doing this also makes it easy to implement "connecting" accounts, so users can link other accounts (say Facebook and Twitter), and then login using either.

Comment: OK, so it'll be possible that two differents account providers could have same ID?

Comment: Yep.  Many providers just use auto-incrementing IDs as user IDs.  Both Twitter and Foursquare did (in the early days, they've since changed).  You might see ID 1001 from Twitter and ID 1001 from Foursquare, but those are two separate accounts from two different providers.  There is no relation between the IDs (other than the number) and they do not identify the same person.